# SQL Server Read and Write Latency

Tags: sql-server-2012, latency

I am facing some slowness in my production SQL Server 2012 database.

When I check the latency, it shows the Read latency of my `.MDF` file exceeds the critical (21 ms) sometimes and most of the time in warning level (now 18 ms).

What is the cause of this? How can I resolve this? Is this is the cause for DB Hang?

Comment: See [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/03/io-subsystem/monitoring-read-write-latency)

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: Best guess is that your IO operations are slow due to hardware. Without a lot more information though, we really can't offer anything more than a guess.